# Corrispective of android:weight in JavaFX

Tags: java, android, javafx, android-layout-weight

I'm developing a small software for training in JavaFX.

In Android, inside a `LinearLayout`, I can expand a view to fill the whole space available by setting the variable `android:weight="someValue"`, unfortunately I'm unable to achieve this is JavaFX.

I've tried to work with the max/min/pref height but it didn't work.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `VBox`/`HBox` you can set the `vgrow`/`hgrow` static property of the children (or some of them) to `Priority.ALWAYS` which makes those `Node`s grow when the parent grows (assuming they are resizable).

```
private static Region createRegion(String color) {
    Region region = new Region();
    region.setStyle("-fx-background-color: "+color);
    return region;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    VBox vbox = new VBox(
            createRegion("red"),
            createRegion("blue"),
            createRegion("green")
    );
    for (Node n : vbox.getChildren()) {
        VBox.setVgrow(n, Priority.ALWAYS);
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

To control the relative weights of the children, you could use a `GridPane` instead and set the `percentWidth`/`percentHeight` properties of the `ColumnConstraints`/`RowConstraints`.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    GridPane root = new GridPane();

    root.getColumnConstraints().addAll(DoubleStream.of(30, 2, 68)
            .mapToObj(width -> {
                ColumnConstraints constraints = new ColumnConstraints();
                constraints.setPercentWidth(width);
                constraints.setFillWidth(true);
                return constraints;
            }).toArray(ColumnConstraints[]::new));

    RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints();
    rowConstraints.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

    root.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints);

    root.addRow(0, Stream.of("red", "green", "blue").map(s -> createRegion(s)).toArray(Node[]::new));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();
}
```